# Set data attribute with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I've this line of code :

```
<p class="main-description" >Hello world</p>
```

I want to add a data attribute with JQuery, I can't change the HTML

So I try this :

```
$('.main-description').data('data-custom','5s');
```

The final result should be this but **it does not work**

```
<p class="main-description" data-custom="5s" >Hello world</p>
```

Comment: also it should be `data('custom','5s');`

Comment: try `$('.main-description').attr('data-custom','5s');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **[`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

```js
$('.main-description').attr('data-custom', '5s');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="main-description">Hello world</p>
```

For the difference between them refer  : [jQuery Data vs Attr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr)